# Keras Dropout layer does not appear to work

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a relatively straightforward Keras model that I have seen many other people use in the literature. In its simplified form, it looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(n, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
model.add(Dense(m, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
model.add(Dense(p))
```

where `n,m,p` are some arbitrary dimensions, and `dropout` is the dropout rate. I train the model like this

```
                model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')

                lossHistory = keras.callbacks.History()
                model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                                    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
                                    epochs=epochs,
                                    validation_data=valid_generator,
                                    validation_steps=validation_steps,
                                    callbacks = [lossHistory])
```

Nothing crazy here. The problem is that the dropout parameter seems to have no effect. The reason I say that is that I am getting a lot of overfitting, regardless of the dropout value I use (I have tried 0.1,0.2,..., 0.95).

Therefore, to try to diagnose the problem, I wanted to try the extreme values (dropout = 0 and 1). I might be misunderstanding what the dropout number represents, but one of these values should result in everything getting dropped out, thereby making the model essentially untrainable (since it should return a constant output). However.... with a dropout value of 0 the training looks like:

```
1/20 [>.............................] - ETA: 139s - loss: 0.9623
2/20 [==>...........................] - ETA: 87s - loss: 0.7758 
3/20 [===>..........................] - ETA: 68s - loss: 0.6146
```

then with a dropout value of 1, the training looks like:

```
 1/20 [>.............................] - ETA: 178s - loss: 0.2134
 2/20 [==>...........................] - ETA: 102s - loss: 0.2295
 3/20 [===>..........................] - ETA: 76s - loss: 0.2368
```

This should be impossible. What am I missing here guys? Dropout has been very useful for me in my Tensorflow models, but something appears to be wrong with how I am implementing it in Keras...

Just for the record, a snippet of model.summary() returns

```
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 50)                550       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 50)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 51
```

So it does seem to me that the dropout layer is actually in the model (not some dumb bug where I accidentally excluded it from the model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the dropout to 0 or 1 results in ignoring the dropout layer according to [the layer definition](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py#L109) in the source code.

```
def call(self, inputs, training=None):
    if 0. < self.rate < 1.:
        noise_shape = self._get_noise_shape(inputs)

        def dropped_inputs():
            return K.dropout(inputs, self.rate, noise_shape,
                             seed=self.seed)
        return K.in_train_phase(dropped_inputs, inputs,
                                training=training)
    return inputs
```

Comment: This answers one of the specific problems in the question, but not the general spirit of the question, which is whether the dropout usage in the above example is correct.

Comment: Yes, sorry, looking a bit more in kera's backend definition, `K.dropout()` is [just calling `tf.nn.dropout()`](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py), I used kera's dropout layer successfully in a couple of models, so I would say "it works for me". You may need to check if you have enough data or spend a little more time in the feature engineering, try to visualize your data and see if you can remove some noise from it.